# C# webapp internal notification system design

Tags: c#, web-applications, notifications, aws-lambda, publish-subscribe

I'm new to web application design and I appreciate if you can share you experience and knowledge on the following question.

Usecase / background:
I'm building a web app that keeps track of our customer interactions. When a customer starts interact with my webapp, I have to make an API call saying interaction is ACTIVE. When this customer stops the interaction​, I'm setting the customer state to IDLE with a time limit of 30 minutes. After the 30 minutes of inactivity, I have to make another API call saying interaction is ENDED.

My current approach:
I'm saving the IDLE customers' user IDs to a database (redis). I also have a scheduled event that fires every minute which queries my IDLE id database. When I find the expired ids (pass 30 mins), I delete those ids and make the final API call (ENDED).

Question:
Is there a better way to implement this considering scalability and reliability? Ideally, I'd like a notification system where I can make an API call to register to a notification with a customer id, a time limit, and a callback URL. When the time limit expires given callback URL endpoint should be notified. Is there a industry accepted solution for like this? If yes, is it really better than my current approach? How would you implement the very system?

Any feedback anf design tips will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I quite like your approach - what about: on each customer interaction subscribe to an event, plus passing up the datetime of interaction for comparison - if date greater than 30mins fire event, it will fire event for all subscribers within the date range. To add a bit of realtime notification add in SignalR too.

Comment: Thanks @TezWingfield. Can you please tell me what's the preferred way of subscribing to an event in web apps? Is there a way to fire an event with a time limit? So, the event will be invoked automatically after 30 mins, without a manual query every minute.